# Loading multiple images from a file path

Tags: c#, image, bitmap, openfiledialog

BackGround: I have a (winform) code which can load an image from a specific file path by using Openfile dialog, then the bitmap was further extracted the brightest pixel of the bitmap and fitted the variation of brightness along x pixel which then produced and fitted to a Gaussian distribution, (the pictures are taken from a Gaussian laser beam.)

Question :Now What I need to do next is to do the same thing over 20 individual pictures, However, I found this is immensely difficult to do in c# and therefore need some help.

Ignore about extracting the brightness pixel and fitting a Gaussian , what I want to do first is to load the images, before further image processing.

I tried to create a new class called Myclass, which takes an argument integer i, and it will open the file according to the integer i I assigned to it. Since I got 0.bmp,1.bmp,2.bmp,... etc in the file path @"C:\Users\Desktop\A.
Now , for each object in the myListOfObjects , I want them to Load a different bitmap picture so that it gets saved in each of these object.

e.g. myListOfObjects[0] has bitmap 0.bmp
myListOfObjects [1] has bitmap 1.bmp....

(so then later I can run a for_loop to the list to find brightest pixel of each image in each object)

I know this question might seem a little bit specific, but the general idea overall is to load multiple images and save individual images into each object (and I have found no similar examples in stackoverflow).

```
private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var myListOfObjects = new List<MyClass>();// This line produces a list of empty objects which is not something I want, I want a list of objects which is not empty.

    for (var i = 0; i < 20; i++)
    {
      myListOfObjects.Add(new MyClass(i));
    }
}
public class MyClass
{
    public MyClass(int i)
    {

    }
    private void OpenAbitmap(int i )
    {
        Bitmap picture = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Desktop\A\" + i.ToString() + ".bmp");

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you trim down your story to the actual question? It's not clear to me what you want to happen. What should the list be initialized with?

Comment: @CodeCaster Hi I just editted with Background and  Question. 
The thing is I originally have a winform program which finds a load a bitmap, and find its brightest point,...etc etc all sorts of amazing image processing can happen afterwards.
However, now I was asked to do the same thing but for 20 pictures.

Comment: @CodeCaster So I came up with this Idea to store all objects in a list, and each object can contain a different bitmap, and each object has function to do the image processing on its own afterwards.

Comment: The main problem i'm having now is that 
var myListOfObjects = new List<MyClass>() <-- this creates a list of objects which are empty, but I want them to have the functions I defined.

Comment: @szpic would the multiseclect allow me to open 20 bitmap and hold them in the memory and do the magic?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "empty objects" you mean you can't call functions on it, that's right: you declared the only method as  `private`. You also don't store the constructor parameter.

You'll need something like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    private int _index;

    public MyClass(int i)
    {
        _index = i;
    }
    public void OpenAbitmap()
    {
        Bitmap picture = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Desktop\A\" + _index.ToString() + ".bmp");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks A lot ! I think I will try and see if there's any problem with it.